# Buscar un elemento en un array con recursividad

Tags: java, array

La situación es la siguiente, estoy muy nuevo en la programación y estoy viendo recursividad.

Estoy tratando de encontrar la cantidad de numeros pares dentro de una matriz, usando recursividad, pero me da error y no se que es. Se que quizás es muy fácil, pero no veo la manera.

```
int [][] matriz = new int [3][3];
     matriz[0][0] = 15; 
     matriz[0][1] = 10; 
     matriz[0][2] = 21; 
     matriz[1][0] = 18; 
     matriz[1][1] = 3; 
     matriz[1][2] = 6; 
     matriz[2][0] = 24; 
     matriz[2][1] = 80; 
     matriz[2][2] = 21; 
       
   System.out.printf("La cantidad de números pares en la matriz es %d \n", numeroPareMatrizRecursiva(matriz, 0, 0, 0));
 }

 public static int numeroPareMatrizRecursiva(int [][] arreglo, int i, int j, int cantidadPares){
  if (i== arreglo.length){
      return cantidadPares;
  }else{
      if(arreglo[i][j]%2 == 0){
          return numeroParesMatrixRecursiva(arreglo, i, j+1, cantidadPares+1);
          
  }else{
         return numeroParesMatrizRecursiva(arreglo, i, j+1, cantidadPares); 
      }
     
  }
```

Comment: Me parece  que nunca  vas a salir de la recursividad  porque para ello la variable i debe llegar  al numero de elementos del  arreglo pero nunca aumentas esa variable siempre  es  0.. Quizá sea  j lo  que quieras comparar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que ver las llamadas recursivas como son, una pila LIFO (*Last In First Out*), la cual puedes ver como una montaña de platos. Cuando pones más platos los pones hasta arriba de la pila, cuando quieres sacar un plato, obviamente no sacas el de hasta abajo, sino, el primero.

Entonces siguiendo esa lógica podemos ver las operaciones de esta manera:

1. Primero se va a recorrer la matriz ENTERA, y las variables de cada estado (cada plato de la pila de platos) se almacenarán en STACK
2. A partir de ahí ira de reversa hasta quitar el último plato

**Código**

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] matrix = {{15,10,21}, {18,3,6}, {24,80,21}};

        System.out.printf(
                "%s %d\n",
                "La cantidad de números pares en la matriz es: ",
                countMatrixEvenNumbers(matrix, 0, 0, 0)
        );

    }


    public static int countMatrixEvenNumbers(int[][] matrix, int row, int col, int evens) {
        // Si el número de la fila row y columna col es par, se aumentan los pares
        if (matrix[row][col] % 2 == 0)
            ++evens;
        // Si ya se han recorrido todas las columnas de la fila, se incrementa la fila en 1 y se vuelve a colocar la columna como 0
        if (++col == matrix[row].length){
            ++row;
            col = 0;
        }
        // Mientras aún hayan filas por recorrer, se hace la llamada recursiva
        if (row < matrix.length) {
            evens = countMatrixEvenNumbers(matrix, row, col, evens);
        }
        // se retorna la cantidad de números pares
        return evens;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
La cantidad de números pares en la matriz es:  5
```

**Explicación de lo que está pasando**

1. Se compara si el elemento `matrix[row][col]` es par, de ser así, se incrementa el contador
2. Se compara si todas las columnas de la fila han sido recorridas, de ser así, se pasa a la siguiente fila en la columna 0
3. Se compara si aún hay filas por recorrer

   - De ser así, se llama recursivamente y se vuelve al paso 1 (con el contador actual)
   - De no ser así, se retorna el número de números pares contados y se "quita" la recursividad (se quita un plato de la pila de platos)

Answer (score 2):

Sufri!, hace tiempo no programaba en java. Una función recursiva es aquella que se llama a si misma n veces, lo cual la hace ineficiente para datos u operaciones muy grandes.

Para tu problema debemos verificar cada valor, por lo que tendremos que recorres el array primero en su primera *columna* `0` y luego recorres en sus *filas*, algo como esto:

- primero `[0][0]`
- luego `[0][1]`
- luego `[0][2]`
- cuando llegue al final cambiamos la primera poscicion
- `[1][0]` y asi sucesivamente
- cuando llegue a `[2][2]` habra terminado

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Your code here!
        
    int [][] matriz = new int [3][3];
    matriz[0][0] = 15; 
    matriz[0][1] = 10; 
    matriz[0][2] = 21; 
    matriz[1][0] = 18; 
    matriz[1][1] = 3; 
    matriz[1][2] = 6; 
    matriz[2][0] = 24; 
    matriz[2][1] = 80; 
    matriz[2][2] = 21; 
    
    // System.out.println(matriz.length);
    numeroPareMatrizRecursiva(matriz,0,0);
    }
    
    
    
    public static void numeroPareMatrizRecursiva(int [][]arreglo,int i, int j){
        
        // System.out.println("el valor de i es:");
        // System.out.println(i);
        // System.out.println("el valor de j es:");
        // System.out.println(j);
        // System.out.println("-----------------");
        
        // obtenemos el numero
        int num = arreglo[i][j];
        
        int longArr = arreglo.length-1;
        
        boolean stop = false;
        //reseteamos las variable j y aumentamos la variable i
        if(j == longArr && i<longArr){
            i = i+1;
            j = -1;
        }else if (j == longArr && i == longArr){
            System.out.println("termino");
            stop = true;
        } 
        
        // comprobamos si es par
        if (num%2 == 0){
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        
        if (stop == false){
            j = j+1;
            numeroPareMatrizRecursiva(arreglo,i,j);
        } 
        
    }

}
```